# Gradle tries to compile jars' sources

Tags: java, gradle

In my project I've got some java sources created by my company and dependency jars' which contains sources. The problem is that command `compileJava` tries to compile also jars sources. How to avoid this? I want to compile only my sources, not jars' sources.

**[UPDATE]**

Here is an example how does it look like:

```
apply plugin: 'java'

tasks.withType(JavaCompile) {
    options.compilerArgs = ["-implicit:none"] // this doesn't work
    //options.compilerArgs << "-implicit:none" // this one also
}

repositories {
    mavenCentral()
}

dependencies {
    compile 'com.company:myLib:1.0'
}
```

`myLib` contains java sources which are compiled by gradle but they shouldn't.

Comment: Can you provide some details about your gradle script?

Comment: Your dependency should include the fact that you need the jar.

Answer (score 0):

Gradle only compiles sources for modules or projects that have (1) have sources and (2) have the java plugin applied.

If you want to disable compilation or creation of jars of a specific project, you can use syntax like this:

```
project("Project123") { 
    compileJava.enabled = false
    //AND / OR
    jar.enabled = false
}
```

**EDIT**

If however, you are pulling a dependency from an external source like ivy, you can try including the type of the dependency:

```
compile 'myLib:myLib:1.0:jar'
```

Answer (score 0):

What you are describing is the standard behavior of the Java compiler, and can be turned off in the same way as for the command line compiler:

```
tasks.withType(JavaCompile) {
    options.compilerArgs = ["-implicit:none"]
}
```

Answer (score 0):

I had the same issue - turns out setting an empty source path solves the problem

`tasks.withType(JavaCompile) {
    options.compilerArgs += ["-sourcepath", ""]
}`

I'm curious as to why `-implicit:none` doesn't work but not enough to investigate this further (at least not now).

*Source: Peter's answer in [this post](http://forums.gradle.org/gradle/topics/compilation_fails_when_i_use_guavas_optional_class_duplicate_class_com_google_common_collect_abstractiterator).*